# Video playing: Skipped frame when on battery

Tags: xorg, display, intel-graphics, hardware-acceleration

When I'm playing a video on battery (either youtube ([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cyxixzi2dgQ)), or local VLC ), there is noticeable stutter/skipped frame only when I'm battery powered.

I guess there is some kind of power optimisation to disable somewhere ?

env: ubuntu 20.04 on thinkpad t14s (integrated intel graphics), hardware acceleration enabled

PS:
The refresh rate settings GUI also looks kinda weird, I have a 60hz screen but a bunch of option shows up (59.9Hz, 60.03Hz, 119.94Hz, 120.02Hz, I've selected 60.03Hz):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit !!!!
It's indicator-multiload, uninstalled it
https://launchpad.net/indicator-multiload